# Create dropdown menu within a popup window

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a list of records in multiple sheets (same workbook).
I currently have a dropdown menu within my googlesheet where if you select one of the records it will delete the row with that record. 
However, I would like to give the option to either move it to another sheet or delete it. I was trying to use UiApp but then found out alot of the options are deprecated and that now I have to use HTMLService.
So what I'm looking to do is, once I select a record, have a popup that has two options.

Option 1 : a Move option (button) with a dropdown of the names of the other sheets within the workbook that will then move that record to that sheet
Option 2 : Delete the record
Option 3 : Cancel.

Is this possible? and if so, would someone be able to guide me to the right direction or a similar example so I can try and figure out how to get that going?

Comment: DId you have a look at [sidebars](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showSidebar(Object))?

Comment: Yes, I did look into that. However, the issue is I'm totally lost on how I could get a dropdown menu within the popup or sidebar that pulls from my sheet. Then when I select the record, have it then reference back to the sheet to perform the move or delete the record. I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how I would get that to work with in the HTML page. If I had to do it within google scripts only, I can do it, but I just need a little guidance on how to tie that stuff in from the HTML page. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can try creating a [Custom dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs)

> A custom dialog can display an HTML service user interface inside a Google Docs, Sheets, or Forms editor.
>
> Custom dialogs do not suspend the server-side script while the dialog is open. The client-side component can make asynchronous calls to the server-side script using either the google.script API for HTML-service interfaces or server handlers for UI-service interfaces.

Code.gs

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Show dialog', 'showDialog')
      .addToUi();
}

function showDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page')
      .setWidth(400)
      .setHeight(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(html, 'My custom dialog');
}
```

Page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <select>
       <option>Delete</option>
       <option>Move</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]
With that, try reading about [HTML Service: Communicate with Server Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

> [**`google.script.run`**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) is an asynchronous client-side JavaScript API that allows HTML-service pages to call server-side Apps Script functions. The following example shows the most basic functionality of **`google.script.run`** — [calling a function on the server](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#myFunction(...)) from client-side JavaScript.

Here is a sample code for form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      // Prevent forms from submitting.
      function preventFormSubmit() {
        var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
        for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
          forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
          });
        }
      }
      window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);

      function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateUrl).processForm(formObject);
      }
      function updateUrl(url) {
        var div = document.getElementById('output');
        div.innerHTML = '<a href="' + url + '">Got it!</a>';
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
      <input name="myFile" type="file" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <div id="output"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Mate, can page.html be dynamically created within google apps script?

Comment: @Riccardo it has been suggested in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74719027/5211833) "can use a template for page.html - see [Google Sheets Sidebar User Input Drop-down Menu w/ Values from Spreadsheet Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60835430/google-sheets-sidebar-user-input-drop-down-menu-w-values-from-spreadsheet-range) for example."