# Google Sheets Sidebar User Input Drop-down Menu w/ Values from Spreadsheet Range

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script, google-sheets, drop-down-menu, sidebar

I have read a bunch of forum posts about using drop-down menus in Google Sheets, but I'm really not familiar enough with scripting to modify those solutions to meet my needs. I would really appreciate any help I can get with this!

This sidebar adds a new entry to the end of my Job Log sheet. It currently works with text inputs, but I want some of the fields to be drop-down menus with options from various dynamic ranges in the spreadsheet.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xq1x8.png)
[Sandbox Copy of Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10pv5KvQYloxmx_7wQxlySTQslCQBFTcWwAsvkLHop7Y/edit?usp=sharing)

1. Drop-down options will populate when sidebar is opened with showNewJobSidebar()
2. Inputs for Turnaround, Category, Upcharge, Discount, Client, and Type will be drop-down menus

Here are the dynamic data ranges to use:

- Turnaround = Rates!A2:A
- Category = Rates!B2:B
- Upcharge = Upcharges!A2:A
- Discount = Discounts!A2:A
- Client = Roster!A2:A
- Type = Data!A2:A

Applicable parts of Code.gs:

```js
function showNewJobSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService
      .createHtmlOutputFromFile('NewJobSidebar')
      .setTitle('New Job Sidebar')
      .setWidth(200);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showSidebar(html);
}

function applyNew(turnaround, category, upcharge, discount,
datein, timein, datedue, timedue, client, type, description, pages) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Job Log");

  //Select the column we will check for the first blank cell
  var columnToCheck = sheet.getRange("B:B").getValues();
  
  // Get the last row based on the data range of a single column.
  var lastRow = getLastRowSpecial(columnToCheck);
  
  var selectedRow = lastRow + 1;

  //Apply turnaround to Column B = Column 2
  sheet.getRange(selectedRow, 2).setValue(turnaround);
  //Apply category to Column C = Column 3
  sheet.getRange(selectedRow, 3).setValue(category);
  //Apply upcharge to Column D = Column 4
  sheet.getRange(selectedRow, 4).setValue(upcharge);
  //Apply discount to Column E = Column 5
  sheet.getRange(selectedRow, 5).setValue(discount);
  //Apply datein to Column F = Column 6
  sheet.getRange(selectedRow, 6).setValue(datein);
  //Apply timein to Column G = Column 7
  sheet.getRange(selectedRow, 7).setValue(timein);
  //Apply datedue to Column H = Column 8
  sheet.getRange(selectedRow, 8).setValue(datedue);
  //Apply timedue to Column I = Column 9
  sheet.getRange(selectedRow, 9).setValue(timedue);
  //Apply client to Column L = Column 12
  sheet.getRange(selectedRow, 12).setValue(client);
  //Apply type to Column M = Column 13
  sheet.getRange(selectedRow, 13).setValue(type);
  //Apply description to Column N = Column 14
  sheet.getRange(selectedRow, 14).setValue(description);
  //Apply pages to Column O = Column 15
  sheet.getRange(selectedRow, 15).setValue(pages);
  
};

function getLastRowSpecial(range){
  var rowNum = 0;
  var blank = false;
  for(var row = 0; row < range.length; row++){

    if(range[row][0] === "" && !blank){
      rowNum = row;
      blank = true;
    }else if(range[row][0] !== ""){
      blank = false;
    };
  };
  return rowNum;
};
```

NewJobSidebar.html:

```html
<body bgcolor="#039EB2">
  <font face="arial" color="white">
    <b>Enter new job details.</b><br><br>
    
    <!-- Create input fields to accept values from the user -->
    Turnaround:<br>
    <input type="text" id="Turnaround"><br><br>
    
    Category:<br>
    <input type="text" id="Category"><br><br>
    
    Upcharge:<br>
    <input type="text" id="Upcharge"><br><br>
    
    Discount:<br>
    <input type="text" id="Discount"><br><br>
    
    Date In:<br>
    <input type="text" id="DateIn"><br><br>
    
    Time In:<br>
    <input type="text" id="TimeIn"><br><br>
    
    Date Due:<br>
    <input type="text" id="DateDue"><br><br>
    
    Time Due:<br>
    <input type="text" id="TimeDue"><br><br>
    
    Client:<br>
    <input type="text" id="Client"><br><br>
    
    Type:<br>
    <input type="text" id="Type"><br><br>
    
    Description:<br>
    <input type="text" id="Description"><br><br>
    
    Pages:<br>
    <input type="text" id="Pages"><br><br>
    
    <!-- Create a button to update values -->
    <button onclick='saveNew()'>Save New Job</button><br><br><br>
    
<script>

  function saveNew(){
   //Get the value of the input fields 
   var turnaround = document.getElementById("Turnaround").value
   var category = document.getElementById("Category").value
   var upcharge = document.getElementById("Upcharge").value
   var discount = document.getElementById("Discount").value
   var datein = document.getElementById("DateIn").value
   var timein = document.getElementById("TimeIn").value
   var datedue = document.getElementById("DateDue").value
   var timedue = document.getElementById("TimeDue").value
   var client = document.getElementById("Client").value
   var type = document.getElementById("Type").value
   var description = document.getElementById("Description").value
   var pages = document.getElementById("Pages").value
   
   //Log input values in the web browser console
   console.log(turnaround, category, upcharge, discount,
   datein, timein, datedue, timedue, client, type, description, pages)

   //Send values as arugments to the server side function
   google.script.run.applyNew(turnaround, category, upcharge, discount,
   datein, timein, datedue, timedue, client, type, description, pages)
  }
  
</script>
    
  </font>
  </body>
```

Comment: Here's a simple dialog: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59345869/7215091

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a dynamic dropdown you will have to use a HTML template that enables you to create dynamic html content. First you fetch the data you need from your spreadsheet and then you pass it to your template.

Build the template and variables from Apps Script:

```
function showNewJobSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('NewJobSidebar');

  // Add the dropdown lists to the template
  html.turnaroundDPDWN = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A2:A5").getValues();

  // Keep adding the variables you need based on the ranges containing your dropdown values
  // ...

  // Prepares the template to be shown in the UI
  html = html.evaluate()
      .setTitle('New Job Sidebar')
      .setWidth(200);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}
```

Add the dynamic dropdowns based on the list you created in Apps Script to your html

```
<body bgcolor="#039EB2">
  <font face="arial" color="white">
    <b>Enter new job details.</b><br><br>

    <!-- Create input fields to accept values from the user -->
    Turnaround:<br>
    <select id="Turnaround">
    <? for (let i in turnaroundDPDWN) { ?>
      <option value="<?=turnaroundDPDWN[i]?>"><?=turnaroundDPDWN[i]?></option>
    <? } ?>
    </select>

    <!-- And so on with the others dropdowns -->
```

### References:

[htmlTemplate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-template)

Comment: I've been sick but now I'm feeling better and have had a chance to test this out. It works perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: i think people learning google apps script would like to know the <?..?> tags are called scriptlets
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#index.html_1